# Prevent a certain user with the Role Sitecore Client Managing from seing the admin account

Tags: security, sitecore, account

Is it possible to prevent user X to see the admin account in the User - Manager? We want to be able to make sure this account will never be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is at all possible. If a user has permissions to run security apps (User Manager), he will see all roles / users there.

Comment: Would you also think it's not possible to hook your own logic into this manager somewhere?

Comment: I don't think so. You can also play with the feature called Locally Managed domains (see chapter 2.5 here: http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc61keywords/securityreference-a4.pdf). But, to be honest, I don't have any experience using it...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this before, but if I was attacking this problem, I would look at subclassing the user manager to remove the admin user before it is shown to the user. WARNING: This is quite a complicated and fragile change and may not be appropriate in your environment so be warned.

If you're interested, then in v6.4.1, I would look at the `onload()` function of the  `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Security.UserManager` class. Specifically at the `managedUsers` variable and possibly removing the admin user from that variable before it is set to be managed by the grid.

That's where I would start, but I'm not sure if it would work as I said, I haven't needed to implement this particular requirement before.